# How to avoid these overlapping elements

Tags: css, position

I was toying with some made code on codepen, trying to get used to html/css since I am not really comfortable on the positioning. This must be pretty silly but I can't make it work.

HTML:

```
<div id="hh">
    <h1>Wacom Hover Effect</h1>
</div>
<div id="cl">
    <a href="#" data-text="Read More" class="button-hover">Read More</a>
    <a href="#" data-text="Learn More" class="button-hover">Learn More</a>
    <a href="#" data-text="Read Article" class="button-hover">Read Article</a>
    <a href="#" data-text="Download" class="button-hover">Download</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*, :before, :after{ @include box-sizing('border-box'); }
body{ padding: 1em; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; background: #eee; }

#hh{
   position:absolute; 
   left:50%
   }

h1{
  position:relative;
  left:-50%;
  font: 300 3em/1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: solid 0.00019em #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background-color:lightblue;
  border-radius:0.2em;
  }
#cl{
   clear:both;
 }

.button,
 [class*="button-"]{

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: 0 4em;
  height: 3.5em;
  font: 300 1em/3.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text:{
    decoration: none;
    shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(black, .35);
   }
  letter-spacing: .08em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0090C0;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  @include transition(.35s ease all);

}
```

}

There is some irrelevant code after that about hovering etc.
The result is this: http://codepen.io/roygbiv/full/FjLcA

So I wanted h1 at center and I found here the method of putting #hh absolute, left:50% and then h1 relative left:-50%. And it screwed up the positioning.

What I want is h1 on center top, then the 4 "a"s under it (not center, just not overlapping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `position: absolute` on an element makes all other elements ignore it. This can be solved by putting `display: inline-block` on the `h1` and `text-align: center` on `#hh`:

Check new pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kovaC

```
#hh {
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  font: 300 3em/1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: solid 0.00019em #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background-color:lightblue;
  border-radius:0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`inline-block` makes the element's box adapt to the width of its text. I presume the desired look of the header is for the blue box to not be `100%` width, which is otherwise the case with `h1` and other block elements.

Answer (score -1):

i have done the following modification in css and it is working as expected:

```
#hh{
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:40%;
}

h1{
  font: 300 3em/1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: solid 0.00019em #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding: 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background-color:lightblue;
  border-radius:0.2em;
}
```

Comment: `top` is not a valid value of the `position` property.